# Given the relation $\{(1,1),(1,2),(2,1),(2,2),(3,3),(4,4)\}$ determine whether it is reflexive, transitive, symmetric, or anti-symmetric.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

> Given the relation $\{(1,1),(1,2),(2,1),(2,2),(3,3),(4,4)\}\,$ determine whether it is reflexive, transitive, symmetric, or anti-symmetric.

I found this set to be reflexive and symmetric. But not transitive and anti-symmetric.

Would it be correct to say that this set would be anti-symmetric if we remove either the element $(1,2)$ or $(2,1)$?

Also, the solution claims this set to be transitive. But I found it not to be so, due to the reasoning that $(2,3)$ and $(3,4)$ is not in the set.

Is my understanding of these ideas correct? Thank you.

Comment: No, the given relation is transitive, since for every $aRb$ and $bRc$, we have $aRc$ in the relation, where $a,b,c\in\{1,2,3,4\}$.

Comment: Transitivity would require $(2,3)$ to be in the set only if there were some $n\in\{1,2,3,4\}$ such that $(2,n)$ and $(n,3)$ were in the set. There is no such $n$, however, so transitivity says nothing about the pair $(2,3)$.

Comment: Just to clarify, on which set is the relation made? Is it $R:A\mapsto A$ where $A=\{1,2,3,4\}$

Comment: @PrasunBiswas Yes, sorry I forgot to include it.

Comment: @Meryll Note that that detail is of paramount importance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is reflexive if this is a relation over the set $\{1,2,3,4\}$, and yes, the relation is symmetric.

Yes, If we remove $(1,2)$ or $(2,1)$ then it is anti-symmetric.

The relation is transitive, we do not need $(2,3)$ and $(3,4)$ to be in the set. Especially there is no pairs in the relation $(2,x)$ and $(x,3)$, which is what we would need in order to force $(2,3)$ to be in the relation due to transitivity.

Comment: So following that, even if we remove $(2,1)$ from the set, it can still remain transitive? Is this correct?

Comment: Yes. Since for the remaining "weird" relation $(1,2)$ we do not have anything on the form $(2,x)$ except for $(2,2)$ which is left in the relation.
Note though that if we remove (1,1) from our original relation, you do not only lose reflexivity, but also transitivity since $(1,2) $ and $(2,1)$ implies $(1,1)$.

Answer (score 1):

is reflexive as (a,a);a=1(1)4 exist,is symmetric as (1,2) nd (2,1) exist and transitive as corrosponding term of (2,1),(1,2)- (1,1) exist in this relation.

Comment: It's rather difficult to understand this answer, as written. Please do what you can to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

It is reflexive as {(1,1),(2,2),(3,3),(4,4)} are present in the set assuming it is a relation of {1,2,3,4} (original set).

Taking (1,1) as an example.

All (x,x) are symmetric too as:
if x = 1, y = 1.
(x,y) ∈ R and (y,x) ∈ R.

All (x,x) are symmetric too as:
if x = 1, y = 1, z = 1
(x,y) ∈ R, (y,z) ∈ R and (x,z) ∈ R.

Here, (1,2) and (2,1) ∈ R, so the only other value that is not reflexive is taken care of by being symmetric.

Taking, (1,2)∈ R, (2,1) ∈ R, (1,1) ∈ R.
taking (2,1) ∈ R, (1,2) ∈, (2,2) ∈ R.

Checking for you, you will see all values have transitive relations existential.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).